# Can you please identify this aircraft from a BBC show?

Tags: aircraft-identification

The image is from:  BBC Skies Above Britain Series 1 "Flying into Danger" - Episode 1
[image]

Comment: "is there a website for aircraft identification?" **Yes**, this one :) We love aircraft identification questions here.

Comment: Unless it's obviously some bad photoshop where there's 20 jet engines on a cessna 172 @Bianfable.

Comment: @GdD For better or worse, we sometimes even deal with [photoshops](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/35958/what-is-the-story-of-this-aircraft)

Comment: I know @Jamiec, we don't love them though.

Answer (score 15):

Although a little hard to read, the reg is `F-BXCP` which you can find with a search

https://www.airport-data.com/aircraft/F-BXCP.html

The aircraft is a [Max Holste MH.1521 Broussard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_Holste_Broussard) which is a 1950's era aircraft originally built for the French airforce.

Somewhat interestingly that aircraft is [now registered](https://www.airport-data.com/aircraft/G-HOUR.html) `G-HOUR` and is owned by the luxury watchmaker "Bremont" (hence the reg). It seems to have first got a reg-change with the same paint scheme and then latterly been repainted.

[image]
[image]